# Fragment Transition - postpone until RecyclerView has laid out relevant elements

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition, android-transitions, fragment-transitions

I'm postponing transition between two fragments which both contain `RecyclerViews` with the trick of creating a fragment, hiding it and only show it when the `RecyclerView` is ready...

Like explained very well here: https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/postponing-fragment-transitions/

My problem is, that this does not work, as the views of the recyclerview seem to not be layout out correctly when the `RecyclerView` is predrawn, this results in wrong transitions (in my case the child views of the `RecyclerView` calculate their sizes in `onCreateViewHolder` and this MUST finish before the transitin starts). Now I adjusted my adapter in that way that the adapter reports when all relevant views are bound, so that I can continue the transition, but this does not work, as then the `RecyclerView` does not start laying out it's child views, probably because the `RecyclerView` is not visible yet...

Can I somehow force the `RecyclerView` to layout it's children even though it's hidden? Any other suggestions?